# Compiled package does not run

Tags: java, classpath, package

I have a package with some classes inside `D:\ProjectGsc\`. The package root folder is called `gsc` and contains three subdirectories namely `util`,`core` and `modules`. Inside each of them are some files and inside `core` there is a file named `gsc.class`. Apart from those there is also a folder `res` inside the `gsc` folder that contains some images that are used by the JFrames and JDialogs inside my package's classes. I manage to compile everything using `-classpath \projectgsc` and, as the code has been debugged, everything is compiled smoothly. But I cannot run it at all. I try to `java gsc -classpath \projectgsc` while I am inside `D:\ProjetctGsc\gsc\core\` but it gives me exception in thread main (syntax of main is correct for sure) `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gsc (wrong name: gsc/core/gsc)`. Is it because of the name of my class being `gsc` inside package `gsc.core`?

Thanks in advance! (Btw SO does not allow me to name the question "Classpath problem when running" so this is the best title I could come up with, feel free to edit it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to run a class called `gsc` (which violates Java naming conventions, btw) in a package `gsc.core` (ick - package name containing the class name; confusing!) you'd write

```
java -classpath d:\ProjectGsc gsc.core.gsc
```

But you'd have to compile it so that you had a directory structure of

```
d:\ProjectGsc
             \gsc
                 \core
                      \gsc.class
```

You'll get this automatically if you use the `-d` option to javac:

```
javac -d d:\ProjectGsc *.java
```

(Adjust accordingly, of course.)

You may well find that if you're new to Java, using an IDE which handles all of this for you would make your life easier.

Comment: I know I violate naming conventions, I am intending to change the name sometime, I was just wanting to check if this works. Thanks will try it out! :)

Comment: @Spiritios: I would urge you to fix your code to follow conventions sooner rather than later. Aside from anything else, any time you ask a question using unconventional names, it makes it that little bit harder for folks to follow the code.

Comment: Ok it works, now can I ask you one more thing because I am quite new to classpaths: when making this into a Jar specifying a classpath will it be fine just like `jar ...parameters... -classpath \projectgsc`? Will it run fine anywhere then or will I have any location-dependencies?

Comment: I will definitely do this as soon as the rest of the classes are finished, but for now I stick to this only for a quick check. Btw I wonder if naming the class `Gsc` will follow conventions?

Comment: @Spiritios: You wouldn't use `-classpath` when *building* the jar file. You just need to make sure that all the relevant files are included, preserving the appropriate directory structure inside the jar file.

Comment: @Spiritios: Yes, `Gsc` would follow the capitalization conventions, although it's not very descriptive.

Comment: Uhm yeah I think I shall take a moment to rename the whole thing now that everything is fine. :)